# How can i forward objects to separate subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView and a ScrollView as 2 separate subviews. How can i drag a UIView(named "a") from my UIView and have the scrollView "take over" that dragged "a" UIView?

Comment: Do you need information about every part or do you already know how to drag a view, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you exactly mean by 'take over' the UIView.

If you simply want to change the parent view, when your view is 'dropped' then remove it as a Subview of it's parent view & add the UIView as a Subview of the UIScrollview.
If the original ParentView has a property that holds the UIView, then it will still retain the instance but the view will be one level down the hierarchy.

If you want to past the entire instance of the view to UIScrollView, you'll have to subclass UIScrollView & add a property for the UIView. Then you can either create a custom setter (i.e. don't `@synthesize`) that will retain the instance & do the above view adding/removing

*OR*

Create a `- (void)provideNewView:(UIView *)newView` method that will assign to the local property and do the view adding/removing.